# knitr: run all chunks in an Rmarkdown document

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I have an .Rmd document which knitr process just fine.

I would like to run all the chunks in the document, so that I can explore the
results in my R shell.

In Rstudio there is an option to run all the chunks in the document,
but I can't find a way to achieve the same effect in a simple R session (opened in my terminal).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `Run all chunks` is equivalent to:

- Create a temporary R file
- Use `knitr::purl` to extract all the R chunks into the temp file
- Use `source()` to run the file
- Delete the temp file

Like this:

```
tempR <- tempfile(fileext = ".R")
library(knitr)
purl("SO-tag-package-dependencies.Rmd", output=tempR)
source(tempR)
unlink(tempR)
```

But you will want to turn this into a function.  This is easy enough, except you have to use `sys.source` to run the R script in the global environment:

```
runAllChunks <- function(rmd, envir=globalenv()){
  tempR <- tempfile(tmpdir = ".", fileext = ".R")
  on.exit(unlink(tempR))
  knitr::purl(rmd, output=tempR)
  sys.source(tempR, envir=envir)
}

runAllChunks("SO-tag-package-dependencies.Rmd")
```

Comment: I just add to midify it slightly but it works like a champ!
here is my modification:
runAllChunks <- function(rmd, envir=globalenv()){
    tempR <- tempfile(tmpdir = ".",fileext = ".R")
    knitr::purl(rmd, output=tempR)
    sys.source(tempR, envir=envir)
    unlink(tempR)
}

Comment: @lucacerone Thank you for spotting the error in my code, and for providing your fix.  I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 8):

You don't even have to use `purl()`: if you `knit` the document in the R console, the code is evaluated in the global environment (by default, see the `envir=` option to `knit()`).

So, if your file is `my.Rmd`, then just run

```
library(knitr)
knit('my.Rmd')
```

A handy trick: if you want to only run up to a certain point in the document, insert an error like:

```
stop('here')
```

at the point in a code chunk you want it to stop, and set the following `knitr` option:

opts_chunk$set(error=FALSE)

in the console before running `knit()`.

Answer (score 0):

load the files in raw text variable

```
file_name="your_file_name.Rmd"
txt <- readLines(file_name)
```

identify beginning and end chunk (first column will be the line where the chunks beginnings for each chunk, and second column will where the chunk ends)

````
chunks <- matrix(grep("```",txt),ncol =  2,byrow = T)
````

select all lines between beginning and end chunk which are the actual code as string

```
temp <- apply(chunks,1,function(x) txt[(x[1]+1):(x[2]-1)])
```

execute the code.(this line executes all the code codded in a string variable)

```
eval(parse(text = temp))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer on how this solves the problem in the question.