# Testing code chunks of a markdown script

Tags: r, r-markdown, testthat

I have a markdown script with several code chunks and providing this script together with my package. 
I want to include unit testing for these code chunks or any way to make sure, my markdown script is always running.

Has anyone tried something before or can recommend a way of testing the markdown script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a function called `runAllChunks` to run R code from an RMD file.  I stole the function from [knitr: run all chunks in an Rmarkdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753969/knitr-run-all-chunks-in-an-rmarkdown-document?answertab=votes#tab-top).  That might be helpful in your situation.

Comment: I try to put the `runAllChunks` function into an `expect_that` function to test if it runs through with my default setting, but `runAllChunks` does not return anything. Would it be save to just return `TRUE` at the end of the function, because if it fails it will produce an error anyways. What do you think or how did you solve this?

Comment: Or you could use `expect_that(runAllChunks(...), not(throws_error()))`.