# devtools::test() works, but devtools::check() fails when testing `expect_known_value()`

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I am building unit tests for an R-package that I am developing. I am using `testthat`, and for some of the functions, I am using `testthat::expect_known_value()`

I am saving the reference files created by `expect_known_value()` in a folder inside the testthat folder "package/tests/testthat/reference_files"

Two of my unit test looks like this:

```
test_that("project_single_joint_to_MP works when .method is 'first_last'", {
  df <- dplyr::filter(mocapr::mocapr_data, movement_nr == 11)

  expect_known_value(project_single_joint_to_MP(df, LSX, LSY, LSZ, "LS", .method = "first_last"), here::here("tests", "testthat", "reference_files", "first_last"))
})

test_that("project_single_joint_to_MP works when .method is 'first_dist'", {
  df <- dplyr::filter(mocapr::mocapr_data, movement_nr == 11)
  expect_known_value(project_single_joint_to_MP(df, LSX, LSY, LSZ, "LS", .method = "first_dist"), here::here("tests", "testthat", "reference_files", "first_dist"))

})
```

I get no erros when running `devtools::test()` or `devtools::test_coverage()`, but when I run `devtools::check()` the two unit tests fails with this message:

```
-- 1. Error: project_single_joint_to_MP works when .method is 'first_last' (@test-project_to_MP.R#12)  -------------------------------------------------------------------
cannot open the connection
1: expect_known_value(project_single_joint_to_MP(df, LSX, LSY, LSZ, "LS", .method = "first_last"), here::here("tests", "testthat", "reference_files", "first_last")) at testthat/test-project_to_MP.R:12
2: saveRDS(object, file, version = version)
3: gzfile(file, mode)

-- 2. Error: project_single_joint_to_MP works when .method is 'first_dist' (@test-project_to_MP.R#17)  -------------------------------------------------------------------
cannot open the connection
1: expect_known_value(project_single_joint_to_MP(df, LSX, LSY, LSZ, "LS", .method = "first_dist"), here::here("tests", "testthat", "reference_files", "first_dist")) at testthat/test-project_to_MP.R:17
2: saveRDS(object, file, version = version)
3: gzfile(file, mode)
```

I have found some answers to similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846465/testthat-fails-within-devtoolscheck-but-works-in-devtoolstest) and [issues](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/144) that suggest adding `Sys.setenv(R_TESTS="")` or `Sys.setenv("R_TESTS" = "")` to the first line in testthat.R, but this does not change anything.

Where should I place the reference files so that `devtools::check()` can open the files?

I am running Rstudio in administrator mode, in case it is relevant.

Session info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] mocapr_0.0.1.9004 forcats_0.4.0     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_0.8.3       purrr_0.3.3       readr_1.3.1       tidyr_1.0.0       tibble_2.1.3      ggplot2_3.2.1    
[10] tidyverse_1.2.1   testthat_2.2.1    usethis_1.5.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-141         fs_1.3.1             xopen_1.0.0          lubridate_1.7.4      devtools_2.2.1       progress_1.2.2       httr_1.4.1          
 [8] rprojroot_1.3-2      tools_3.6.1          backports_1.1.5      utf8_1.1.4           R6_2.4.0             lazyeval_0.2.2       colorspace_1.4-1    
[15] withr_2.1.2          tidyselect_0.2.5     prettyunits_1.0.2    processx_3.4.1       curl_4.2             compiler_3.6.1       cli_1.1.0           
[22] rvest_0.3.4          xml2_1.2.2           desc_1.2.0           scales_1.0.0         callr_3.3.2          commonmark_1.7       digest_0.6.22       
[29] rmarkdown_1.16       pkgconfig_2.0.3      htmltools_0.4.0      sessioninfo_1.1.1    rlang_0.4.0          readxl_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.10     
[36] generics_0.0.2       farver_1.1.0         jsonlite_1.6         magrittr_1.5         Rcpp_1.0.2           munsell_0.5.0        fansi_0.4.0         
[43] lifecycle_0.1.0      stringi_1.4.3        yaml_2.2.0           MASS_7.3-51.4        pkgbuild_1.0.6       grid_3.6.1           crayon_1.3.4        
[50] lattice_0.20-38      haven_2.1.1          hms_0.5.1            zeallot_0.1.0        knitr_1.25           ps_1.3.0             pillar_1.4.2        
[57] pkgload_1.0.2        glue_1.3.1           evaluate_0.14        gganimate_1.0.3.9000 remotes_2.1.0        modelr_0.1.5         vctrs_0.2.0         
[64] tweenr_1.0.1         cellranger_1.1.0     gtable_0.3.0         rcmdcheck_1.3.3      polyclip_1.10-0      assertthat_0.2.1     xfun_0.10           
[71] ggforce_0.3.1        broom_0.5.2          roxygen2_6.1.1       memoise_1.1.0        ellipsis_0.3.0       here_0.1
```

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: No... unfortunately not. I will return to this when I am more familiar with the latest version of testthat (released Auhust 2020).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, my reference files were in package/test/reference_files. But the tests are located in package/test/testthat. Exiting the testthat folder and back into the reference_folder did it for me. That is:

```
expect_known_value(test_depth, '../reference_files/ref_data.rda',
                     update = F, print = TRUE)
```

In your case I would try:

```
expect_known_value(project_single_joint_to_MP(df, LSX, LSY, LSZ, "LS", .method = "first_dist"), "reference_files/first_dist")
```