# My testthat tests pass the devtools::test() check but fail the devtools::check() step when developing an R package

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I have 3 `rds` files I use in my testthat tests. the files are in `/tests/testthat/testdata/`. When I run the tests with `devtools::test()`, the files can be found. When I use `devtools::check()`, the files won't be found.
I have seen this issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510657/devtoolstest-works-but-devtoolscheck-fails-when-testing-expect-known-v) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846465/testthat-fails-within-devtoolscheck-but-works-in-devtoolstest) and [many other places](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/144) but all the suggested solutions won't work for me.
I tried adding the `Sys.setenv(R_TESTS="")` line at the top of my "testthat.R" file; I tried using `here::here()` from the package "here" instead of the , `system.file()` function, etc.
What can I do?

Here is my test:

```
test_that("the test_arguments() returns errors as it should", {
  x <- readRDS(system.file("tests", "testthat", "testdata", "objectA.rds", package = "package"))
  y <- readRDS(system.file("tests", "testthat", "testdata", "objectB.rds", package = "package"))
  z <- readRDS(here::here("tests", "testthat", "testdata", "objectC.rds", package = "package"))

  expect_error(test_arguments(z, y), "X has to be an object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
  expect_error(test_arguments(x, z), "y has to be an object of class RasterLayer")
})
```

And here is the result of the `devtools::check()`:

```
-- Error (test_user_input.R:3:3): the arguments are of the right class ---------------------
Error: cannot open the connection
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-base::readRDS(here::here("tests", "testthat", "testdata", "objectA.rds")) test_user_input.R:3:2
 2.   \-base::gzfile(file, "rb")

[ FAIL 1 | WARN 1 | SKIP 0 | PASS 0 ]
Error: Test failures
Execution halted

1 error x | 1 warning x | 1 note x
```

Comment: It may be worth considering to store the data internally: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#sec-data-sysdata