# Execute all R chunks of an external Rmd file from an R script

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr

I have a .Rmd file called `f1.Rmd` (containing a mix of text and R chunks) and an R script called `f2.R`.

I would like to insert a set of R instructions in `f2.R` that would execute all the R chunks contained in `f1.Rmd`, in such a way that all variables created in `f1.Rmd` would be created in my current R session if I source `f2.R`
(similarly to what happens when clicking on "Run" -> "Run all chunks below from the Rstudio menu").

Comment: Then in F2.R, call `source(f1.r)`

Answer (score 0):

If you render the f1.Rmd file from your current environment, this should happen.
You can use `rmarkdown::render()` from the console or a .R script. This will create all the variables in your current environment. It will also have the side effect of making the document.

When you use the knit button in RStudio, this launches the render in a new r session as a background process.

See also the envir option for render.

See also this answer for other options. [knitr: run all chunks in an Rmarkdown document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24753969/knitr-run-all-chunks-in-an-rmarkdown-document?rq=1)

It also depends what your .Rmd is doing.